# Where is the Terminal Operation sum() implemented in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, stream, java-stream

I see, that it's defined in Interface `IntStream`, but when you write `IntStream.range(0, 200).sum();` how the implementation is called? where is it? couldn't find..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for every interface, it's defined in the concrete class(es) that implement the interface.

In this case, it's in `java.util.stream.IntPipeline`, which is not a public class. But you shouldn't care about that. All you need to know is that an IntStream has that method, which does what the javadoc of the method does.

If you're really curious about its implementation, look in the source code of `IntPipeline.java`:

```
return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Note on how I found out extremely easily: I just open the type hierarchy of `IntStream` in my IDE (IntelliJ, but all decent IDEs have that functionality), and notice that it has a single direct implementation: `IntPipeline`, which indeed contains the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an eligible compiler, there is an option to show its implementation. For example, when I want to see its implementation by IntelliJ, I click *go to implementation*. Then, it redirects.

In `IntPipeLine.java`,

```
@Override
    public final int sum() {
        return reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }
```